# Complex Potential of a Vortex in a Horizontal Strip

Tags: fluid-dynamics

There is fluid in between two boundaries $\operatorname{Im} z = a$ and $\operatorname{Im} z = -a$, with a vortex of strength $Q$ at the origin.

I need to find the complex potential using method of images.

Now, when you have this question but with a line source strength $Q$ instead, you end up with an infinite series of sources  of strength $Q$ as you attempt to balance each boundary. 
However, when I balance the vortex with an image vortex above at $2a$ with strength $-Q$ and the same at $-2a$, it seems to me that the system is balanced, as whichever boundary you look at, the centre vortex seems to balance both the images.

Is this correct, and so I get a potential of 
$$w(z) = -{iQ\over 2\pi}\log(z) + {iQ\over 2\pi}\log(z-2ai) + {iQ\over 2\pi}\log(z+2ai)?$$

I can't really get my head around how vortices intereact with each other, when there is another vortex directly between them.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Thank you. Was wondering how people did that. Hope this edited version is better! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

prove that the two-dimensional irrotational motion of a liquid bounded by the lines y=0,y=2a due to a source at the point(o,a) is given by the complex velocity potential W=-mlogcosh(z/2a)